# mysqli_fetch_assoc() inside loop gets only first row result from WHERE IN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, mysqli

I'm using `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ('$arrayImplodedToStr')` SQL query to get multiple values from database at the same time. The query works fine, because when I echo `$q` I can see all the array items converted to id numbers in query and there are many of them. But when I make a query and store it inside array and then use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` inside `while` loop to get all the rows from query, I always get only one and first item. And can't figure out why?

The code:

```
session_start();
require_once('navigation.php');
require_once('database_connection.php');

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['product_id']);
$arrayImplodedToStr = implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);

$q = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ('$arrayImplodedToStr')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$allRows = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $allRows[] = $row;
}

foreach ($allRows as $cartItems) {
    echo $cartItems['name'];
}
```

Comment: Your query will look something like `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ('1,2,3,4,5')"`, which is incorrect. You need to add single quotes in your implode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want quotes around the array string. That will make it all one item, and - in case of numbers - truncate it to the first one found.

If the individual items are guaranteed to be numbers, remove the quotes. If you might have text strings there, you need to quote each individual item in the string, like `'a', 'b', 'c'` instead of `'a, b, c'`

Comment: Numbers only, removing single quotes breaks the query

Comment: Like you said, It was wrapped in quotes and not individual items in quotes. Fixed it by adding external quotes around `glue` parameter inside `implode` function, like so: `implode("','", $_SESSION['cart']);`

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. But it shouldn't be necessary if all the values are integers.  
Oh well, do you have it working?

Comment: @Limpuls If you **remove the single quotes around $arrayImplodedToStr**, you won't have to add the single quotes in the implode. That's the point of this answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use

$result = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query($query)

Comment: I need assoc array. No OOP